# Is there a kind of programs to illustrate most features and usages of different programming language?

Tags: programming-languages

We all know “The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog” used as benchmark for printing and fonts.

I wonder if there is a similar “Lazy Dog” for Programming Languages.

There are so many different programming languages, with all kinds of features and syntaxs, similar or different. The problem is: the user will be confused when using different languages at the same time.

Although plenty of differences between different languages, there must be something in common, i.e. a task or routine. If we implement the same task in different languages, and try to cover most frequently used features, then the language learning or comparison will become much more easy.

This kind of programme doesn't need to be very long, just like a tutorial but be common and abstract enough. Does it exist?

Comment: **Hello World**?

Comment: @Dan, to be fair, printing is a little trivial.

Comment: Any single short program would have to gloss over 90% of the language features. A large suite of programs may be more appropriate - and that exists at http://rosettacode.org/

Comment: @delnan, you should make that an answer.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt Done.

Comment: hmm I wonder how Unicode people feel about *The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog* ?

Comment: [99 bottles of beer?](http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/)

Comment: @vermiculus: In a purely functional language, printing is anything *but* trivial. In fact, how purely functional languages handle printing is probably one of the key distinguishing factors: Linear Types, Effect Types, World Types, Lazy Streams, Monads, you name it.

Comment: @Frix It doesn't make any sense for Unicode, i.e. Chinese. The phrase for Chinese in linux font viewer is'我能吞下玻璃而不伤身体', which means 'I can eat glass and it doesn't hurt me'.

Comment: @Philipp Interesting site, with many hack skills.

Comment: When talking with a former coworker of mine about this, a poker hand evaluator/comparator (problem #54 at [project euler](http://projecteuler.net/problem=54)) has the opportunity to demonstrate a reasonable amount of language features and philosophy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any single short program would have to gloss over 90% of the language features. Most programming languages are large enough that even a half hour talk can only highlight the key distinguishing characteristics. A *suite* of small-ish programs is more appropriate for exposition and comparison. [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org) is precisely that: A large number of problems are described, and idiomatic solutions in numerous languages are contributed (it's a wiki).

Comment: [Rosetta code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code) is a great site

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I hadn't even known about this!